# Is there any switch for silent uninstallation?

Tags: nsis

Is there any switch for silent uninstallation? like we do `/s` while installing. I tried the same with uninst,exe but didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

It is [documented](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#installerusage) to work for the uninstaller also but it has to be uppercase (/S) and if you are calling the uninstaller from your installer to uninstall a older version you should also provide the special _?= uninstaller parameter. How silent it is depends on your code; a [MessageBox](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#messagebox) without /SD will not be silent etc.

Comment: Reading the documentation, I do not understand, what your mentioned `/SD` in the uninstaller would do. Can you shed some light on that, please? **Update:** I just found out that `/SD` is for `MessageBox`, not for the call of the uninstaller. Sorry for not reading better.

Comment: From the MessageBox documentation: "Use the /SD parameter with one of the return_check values above to specify the option that will be used when the installer is silent." In other words, /SD means silent default. If it is left out, then the message box will still appear to ask the user for input.